# How to add a command to the bash history from python

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, zsh

I am writing a shell wrapper script ([term-cheat](https://github.com/select/term-cheat)) in python that can be used to find, collect and execute shell commands. I would love to add the executed commands to the shell history.
I tried several things like the following but did not succeed.

```
subprocess.Popen('history -s "%s"'%command_string, shell=True, executable=os.environ['SHELL'])
os.system('fc -S "%s"'%command_string)
```

Comment: Here's a hint: Get it to work *without Python* first. When `bash -c 'history -s "foo"'` works, so will `subprocess.Popen(['bash'', '-c', 'history -s "$1"', '_', command_string])`.

Comment: And btw, you note what I did there with `$1`? That's **critically important**. With your code as it is, `command_string='$(rm -rf ~)'` will cause you to run `history -s "$(rm -rf ~)"`, which substitutes *the output of* `$(rm -rf ~)` into your command, and thus needs to run that command to get its output.

Comment: Just switching from double quotes to single quotes won't save you either, because what if the string you're searching for has more single-quotes in it?

Comment: `> zsh -c 'history -s "foo"'
zsh:history:1: bad option: -s
` Ok so I guess the problem is with the zsh that does not accept the -s option

Comment: I switched to bash where `history -s "foo"` works but if I execute `bash -c 'history -s "foo"'` it does not change the history. I also tried from zsh, so I guess this will not work from within python either.

Comment: Look at my answer, and try following its advice: `bash -ic 'set -o history; history -s "foo"'` does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no cross-shell, universally portable option: History is an interactive facility without a close POSIX specification as to how it's implemented.

That said, there are some fixes needed to make the general approach attempted above both functional and safe:

```
subprocess.Popen(['bash', '-ic', 'set -o history; history -s "$1"', '_', command_string])
```

- The HISTFILE variable is only set in *interactive* shells. Thus, you need to run bash with `-i` to have it set at all.
- `set -o history` is similarly needed to turn history *on*.
- Passing `command_string` out-of-band instead of substituting it into the argument following `-c` avoids massive security bugs (where trying to append a line to history could execute parts of it instead).

Comment: Nice this worked, is there a similar solution for the zsh? As stated above zsh history does not accept the `-s` flag.

Comment: Yes, there is one -- see the `print -s` and `print -S` options. No, I don't consider asking for solutions for two completely different, mutually-incompatible shells within reasonable question scope, so I don't intend to do the work to test a solution & add it here.

Comment: Since you now know how to start interactive shells from Python, you should be able to ask a separate question scoped only to zsh with no Python aspects included (f/e, "how can I append to zsh history from a noninteractive shell?")

Comment: I changed the question and maked your answer as the solution, thanks